# Do "Gmail Actions in Inbox" work with any mobile email clients?

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I am sending Actions and they work fine in Chrome/Gmail.

However, I tested GMail.app on Android and iOS and Actions do not show up at all.  Sad panda, mobile seems like a killer app for Actions :-(

Can someone please confirm that Actions are not implemented on mobile apps?

If anyone on the gmail team is reading this, is this feature expected to be implemented on mobile?

Answer (score 2):

Actions in the Inbox are currently not supported by the Android and iOS clients, but mobile is definitely in the roadmap.